# Асинхронность кода на python для сайта

Tags: python, асинхронность

1. Подскажите я правильно понимаю что в общем случае при разработке сайтов, за многопроцессорность и асинхронность и в целом балансировку нагрузки отвечает вебсервер типо nginx apache , а программист пишет обычный синхронный код?
2. Только если пишем свои программы какие то полностью с нуля то там будем полностью реализовать свою балансировку нагрузки?

Comment: 1.Нет; 2. А зачем писать программы полностью с нуля?

Comment: Ну не то чтобы полностью с нуля. Я имею ввиду если мы например пишем свой не веб проект и у нас нет вебсервера который бы делал это всё за нас.

Comment: А почему 1) нет? Я понимаю что в новых версиях django и других фреймворках можно так же писать асинхронный код и т.п. но в целом основную часть распараллеливания всё же забирает на себя версервер? или как ?

Comment: 1. У веб-сервера нет никакой волшебной палочки, которая магическим образом превратила бы синхронный код в асинхронный, он сможет сделать лишь балансировку по заранее запущенным процессам; 2) Ну если не использовать балансировку из себ-сервера, тогда неизбежно придётся искать какую-нибудь другую реализацию или искать свою

Comment: 1. Ну речь не про волшебную таблетку, а про то что грубо говоря если мой скрипт на питоне вызовут 100 человек то у меня всё заткнется. А если тоже самое сделают после вебсервиса то он как минимум это распараллелит по процессам и потокам ну или как предусмотренно непосредственно в нём? и тот же самый скрипт отработает на много сбалансированней? Понятно что код как бы синхронный так и остался.

Comment: 2) Вопрос скорее в том что - на сколько часто программисту приходится писать именно асинхронный\многопроцессорный код который работает после вебсервера? или в большинстве случаев хватает обычного синхронного?

Comment: 1. Ну если вы запустите свой скрипт на питоне в один процесс и один поток, то он точно так же заткнётся хоть с веб-сервером, хоть без него. Впрочем, если вы запустите меньше ста процессов/потоков, то он опять заткнётся, потому что на одновременную обработку всех человек их не хватит. // 2. А это зависит от потребностей конкретного проекта. Если вы делаете небольшой или средний сайт и не злоупотребляете блокирующими вещами вроде лонг-поллинга или вебсокетов, то у вас никогда не будет больше одного-двух запросов работающих одновременно, и синхронный код тоже отлично справится.

Comment: 2. Спасибо понял.

Comment: А по 1) всё таки, я рассматриваю ситуацию когда у меня стоит вебсервер он автоматически (или в полу ручном режиме , точно не знаю как это настраивается) запушен на 10 процессов каждый на 10 потоков итого получаем 100 запросов выполняющих +- параллельно? и вызывая самый обычный синхронный скрипт никак не модифицируя его, он получает возможность одновременно выполнятся для 100 подключений? И без вебсервиса я мог бы добиться того же самого но нужно в коде именно создавать самому процессы и потоки и будет примерно тоже самое?

Comment: Типа того. Но нужно иметь в виду некоторые вещи: 1) каждый процесс будет кушать память, которой случайно может не хватить; 2) в питоне для предотвращения race condition в многопоточной среде используется глобальная блокировка (GIL), которая сводит эффективность потоков почти к нулю; 3) переключение контекста между процессами/потоками — штука не бесплатная и большое их количество может замедлить работу сервера (впрочем, насколько сильно замедлить — не измерял); [...]

Comment: [...] 4) вероятно, «взрослые» веб-серверы применяют какие-нибудь хитрые оптимизации, и своя реализация скорее всего окажется медленнее чем у «взрослых» (но здесь я уже не специалист и тонкостей не знаю)

Comment: Спасибо, понятно!